# Failed to connect to a.b.c.d:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have mongo 3.4 and I have generated my pem files for client and server and below command is starting my mongoDB:

```
sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongo_ssl/server.pem
```

I am able to connect to the DB by following command:

```
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile client.pem --sslCAFile ca.cert --host akshay.abc.com
```

I have used the below command to generate my certs:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new  -sha256 -out server.csr -keyout server.key -subj "/C=IN/ST=DELHI/L=DELHI/O=MongoDB/OU=demoservers/CN=akshay.abc.com" -nodes
```

Below is my mongod.conf file:

```
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  ssl:
        mode: requireSSL
        PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongo_ssl/server.pem
        CAFile: /etc/ssl/mongo_ssl/client.pem

#processManagement:
```

Service is running fine but when I now connect it with mongo command which I used earlier it is giving me the below error:

```
2019-07-04T10:32:24.249+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to a.b.c.d:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2019-07-04T10:32:24.249+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server akshay.abc.com:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?